# Xcode 5 Indexing | Waiting for xcodebuild

Tags: xcode5, xcodebuild

Xcode 5 refuses to index any project. It waits for xcodebuild.
I already deleted derived data, deleted the project.xcworkspace file, clean and restarted. The command line tools are installed. It is Xcode 5.0.2 on OSX 10.8.5.

[image: waiting for xcodebuild]

Answer (score 10):

I have had this behavior occur when my machine was also hosting the Xcode 5 Bots Service -- The `xcodebuild` command line tool was happily running in the background servicing build requests but prevented Xcode's Indexer from being able to do its job...definitely annoying.

- If you are running OS X Server and have the Xcode service running temporarily turn it off.
- Disable any build systems or autonomous testing tools you have running on your development machine.  Many of them rely on `xcrun` and `xcodebuild` to hook into the development process. One or more of those tools may be taking a perpetual lock on xcodebuild behind the scenes.
- Temporarily remove any Xcode plugins you may have installed.
- If you have worked with a cross-platform mobile development tool, consider looking at any daemons those toolchains install and have running on your machine (Activity Monitor will help with that)
- Launch Activity Monitor and forcibly quit any stray `xcodebuild` processes -- Be sure to set your Activity Monitor to show all processes, not just 'My Processes' via View > All Processes.  Sort alphabetically and see if `xcodebuild` is reinvoked shortly after you terminate the process.

After confirming that `xcodebuild` is terminated for all users, relaunch Xcode and see if the Indexer is able to start.

In my case, I had both OS X Server's Xcode Service running as well as a wayward, obsolete 3rd-party Xcode plugin perplexing the Indexer.  Removing the plugin and migrating OS X server to a dedicated machine outside of my development environment resolved the issue for me.

Comment: I have a couple of xcodebuild running in background, I don't know why. But killing them from the Activity Monitor worked. Thanks for the advices.